# access multiple elements of same XML at different depths to convert to R tibble

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have a fairly deep xml file of travel data that I've anonymized here.  I would like to pull out the coupon statuses for multiple segments and attach them to the itinerary id.  I'm having a very difficult time using the xml2 package and I think the reason why is that some of my XML data terminates with text and some terminate with attributes.  I've tried to convert the xml to a list with `as_list()`.  I've also tried to start with `xml_find_all()` but get a nodeset of 0 regardless of the node I search for (Ticketing or Coupons should work, for example).  Below is the data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eTicketCouponRS xmlns="http://webse" xmlns:ns4="http://s" xmlns:stl="http://se" Version="2.0.0">
   <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
      <stl:Success timeStamp="2021-06-16T11:39:52-05:00" />
   </stl:ApplicationResults>
   <TicketingInfos>
      <TicketingInfo>
         <Ticketing AgencyCity="DCA" AgentWorkArea="A" IATA_Number="0952" IssuingAgent="A" PrimeHostID="1S" PseudoCityCode="5SE0" TransactionDateTime="2021-06-16T11:39">
            <CouponData InformationSource="S" IssueDate="2021-03-29" NumBooklets="1" TicketMedia="E" TicketMode="63">
               <AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                  <FareCalculation>
                     <Text>SAN AA X/E/DFW AA TYO M0.00NUC0.00END ROE1.00    XFSAN4.5DFW4.5</Text>
                  </FareCalculation>
                  <ItinTotalFare>
                     <BaseFare Amount="0.00" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                     <Taxes>
                        <Tax Amount="19.10" TaxCode="US" />
                        <Tax Amount="5.60" TaxCode="AY" />
                        <Tax Amount="9.00" TaxCode="XF" />
                     </Taxes>
                     <TotalFare Amount=".70" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                  </ItinTotalFare>
                  <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="GV1" />
               </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
               <Coupons>
                  <Coupon CodedStatus="OK" Number="1" StatusCode="RFND">
                     <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2021-08-13T06:15" FlightNumber="2535" RPH="1" ResBookDesigCode="V">
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DFW" />
                        <FareBasis Code="VCA" />
                        <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="2535" />
                        <OperatingAirline Code="AA" />
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="SAN" />
                     </FlightSegment>
                  </Coupon>
                  <Coupon CodedStatus="OK" Number="2" StatusCode="RFND">
                     <FlightSegment ConnectionInd="X" DepartureDateTime="2021-08-13T12:20" FlightNumber="175" RPH="2" ResBookDesigCode="V">
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="HND" />
                        <FareBasis Code="VCA" />
                        <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="175" />
                        <OperatingAirline Code="AA" />
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW" />
                        <FareTypeClass>PG</FareTypeClass>
                        <FareTypeRule>OW-GO</FareTypeRule>
                     </FlightSegment>
                  </Coupon>
               </Coupons>
               <CustomerInfo>
                  <Customer>
                     <Invoice Number="126" />
                     <Payment ApprovalID="03" RPH="1" ReferenceNumber="XXXXXXXXXXXX" Type="CC">
                        <CC_Info>
                           <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpirationDate="XX-XX" />
                        </CC_Info>
                     </Payment>
                     <PersonName NameReference="PCS" PassengerType="GV1">
                        <GivenName>VER</GivenName>
                        <Surname>DE</Surname>
                     </PersonName>
                  </Customer>
               </CustomerInfo>
               <ItineraryRef CustomerIdentifier="R5" ID="EXAMPLE" />
            </CouponData>
         </Ticketing>
      </TicketingInfo>
   </TicketingInfos>
</eTicketCouponRS>
```

I have about 100 of these each to load separately and pull out a small table consisting of the following columns:
SuccTimeStamp TransacTimeStamp ItineraryID  CouponNumber  StatusCode  Origin  Destination  OperatingAirline FlightNumber.

You can see that each of these elements are found at different depths of the xml and every travel itinerary has a different number of coupons, anywhere from 1-10.  I also found a helpful post here from hrbrmstr helping out someone from 2018, but I can't get a similar solution to "see" my nodes and I'm not sure if it's my code or my xml data.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nested XML files which you need to flatten for end use needs such as R, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. You can run XSLT 1.0 scripts in R using the `xslt` package (sister to `xml2`). Alternatively, you can use a dedicated [XSLT processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) and have R call the external program with `system()`. Like SQL, XSLT is an industry, portable language not limited to R.

Within XSLT, since your granularity is coupon, you can extract from `<Coupon>` level and use the `ancestor::` XPath axe to retrieve higher up level information. Due to the default namespace needs, the long-windeed `<xsl:element>` is used. `IATA_Number` is assumed to be *ItineraryID*.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://webse"
                              xmlns:stl="http://se">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/w:eTicketCouponRS">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:Coupon"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="w:Coupon">
     <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:element name="SuccTimeStamp" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::w:eTicketCouponRS/stl:ApplicationResults/stl:Success/@timeStamp"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="TransacTimeStamp" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::w:Ticketing/@TransactionDateTime"/>              
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="ItineraryID" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::w:Ticketing/@IATA_Number"/>              
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="CouponNumber" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="StatusCode" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="@CodedStatus"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Origin" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="w:FlightSegment/w:OriginLocation/@LocationCode"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Destination" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="w:FlightSegment/w:DestinationLocation/@LocationCode"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="OperatingAirline" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="w:FlightSegment/w:OperatingAirline/@Code"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="FlightNumber" namespace="http://webse">
              <xsl:value-of select="w:FlightSegment/@FlightNumber"/>
          </xsl:element>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTK4)</kbd>

**R**

```r
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# LOAD XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml("/path/to/Input.xml")
style <- read_xml("/path/to/Style.xsl", package = "xslt")

# RUN TRANSFORMATION AND SEE OUTPUT
flat_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)
cat(as.character(flat_xml))

# RETRIEVE data NODES
nmsp <- c(w = "http://webse")
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(flat_xml, "//w:Coupon", ns=nmsp)

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME
df_list <- lapply(recs, function(r) {
  vals <- xml2::xml_children(r)
  
  data.frame(rbind(setNames(c(xml2::xml_text(vals)), 
                            c(xml2::xml_name(vals)))))
})

# COMBINE ALL DFS
final_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
rm(recs, df_list)
```

```r
final_df
#               SuccTimeStamp TransacTimeStamp ItineraryID CouponNumber StatusCode Origin Destination OperatingAirline FlightNumber
# 1 2021-06-16T11:39:52-05:00 2021-06-16T11:39        0952            1         OK    SAN         DFW               AA         2535
# 2 2021-06-16T11:39:52-05:00 2021-06-16T11:39        0952            2         OK    DFW         HND               AA          175
```

Above runs for a single XML. For 100 separate files, wrap above in a user-defined method and run `lapply` for a list of XML dataframes for master concatenation at very end. Load XSLT once outside loop since it does not change, assuming XML files retain same structure.

```r
style <- read_xml("/path/to/Style.xsl", package = "xslt")

xml_to_df <- function(xml_file) { ... }
xml_dfs <- lapply(list_of_xml_files, xml_to_df)

master_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, xml_dfs)
```

Comment: Wow, Parfait, this is super helpful.  I didn't know there was an additional "helper" package , XSLT.  Do I just copy/paste your XSLT text complete with <> into notepad and save as .XSLT?  Now that I see the structure of the style sheet, I may make some edits to bring in some more columns, but what you've provided seems to be complete enough!  It also looks like I can have only 1 single XSLT file to use to parse all of my 100 XMLs, is that correct??

Comment: Yes, save the XSLT scriot which is an XML file as a text file (any extension but .xsl or .xslt for better identification). Adjust as needed and use on all similar structured XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Parfait!  I was able to modify the template xsl that you provided.  The xsl sheet seems to "parse" everything nicely!  After I got it "flattened", all I simply had to do was `as_list()`, `as_tibble()` and  `unnest()` a couple of times and then it was a data frame.

Thanks!